# jQuery draggable text selection bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I am not sure if this is a bug - but in this example there is no way to select the text underneath the elements that can be dragged.

Same issue with form elements.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/handle.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the source code for that page, you'll see that it calls

```
$("div, p").disableSelection();
```

... which explicitly disables selection on all `div`s and `p`s on the page, including those beneath the draggable elements.

Answer (score 2):

The "official" jQuery way of doing things is to use .disableSelection(). However, often times in practice, that does absolutely nothing. In this case you can bolt down all text on the page with

```
document.onselectstart = function () { return false; }
```

Comment: This works great. Usually when someone is in the draggable plugin and is dragging they will not want to select any text on the page.