# jQuery Draggable cannot highlight for copy and paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, copy-paste, jquery-ui-draggable

I make use of [jQuery UI's Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) functionality to make it so you can click and drag a table row.  Unfortunately when I want to highlight the text to copy the data in one of the table cells, it starts dragging the row away.  So I used the "distance" option like so:

```
$('.test').draggable({
revert: 'invalid',
helper: 'clone',
distance: 150,
start: function(event, ui) {
}
});
```

However my problem is that it still won't let me "highlight" the table row, even if it is prior to "dragging" it. :(

Oh btw, I'm just using a regular HTML table, IE:

```
<table>
<tr class="test"><td>Data</td></tr>
<tr class="test"><td>Data</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Another Q&A on this topic has a solution and it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632796/jquery-draggable-text-selection-bug) explains the way to run `disableSelection` on all the elements within your items that are selectable to make it possible to select text for copy and paste and other uses. So for your problem, you could do:

```
$('td').disableSelection();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It doesn't appear to be working though :(